# numpy array, h[:]=h+1 vs. h=h+1

Tags: arrays, variables, numpy, global, internal

Seems like h[:]=h+1 and  h=h+1 all add 1 to all elements in h.

But difference may be found here below, can you explain why?? Looks like in the second case, h is not only changing as an function internal variable, but also acting like overriding the global variable h...This is so confusing...
Thank you for any input!

```
import numpy as np

def fun(h):
    h=h+1
    return h

h=np.zeros((2,2))+1
hI=h.copy()

for i in range(0,3):          
    hI = fun(h) 

print h
print hI
[[ 1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.]]
[[ 2.  2.]
 [ 2.  2.]]
```

Whereas

```
import numpy as np

def fun(h):
    h[:]=h+1
    return h

h=np.zeros((2,2))+1
hI=h.copy()

for i in range(0,3):          
    hI = fun(h) 

print h
print hI

[[ 4.  4.]
 [ 4.  4.]]
[[ 4.  4.]
 [ 4.  4.]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not surprising. I think you are being confused by the fact that you happen to have named your variable `h` in use of the function `fun`. But the name of that variable doesn't matter, and it is *not* reaching up to the parent scope to modify the variable `h` ... rather, the argument passed to `fun` is a *name* for something, not a copy of it. So mutations internal to `fun` still affect the object being named, (in this case, that object is the global scoped `h` array).

To show this more clearly, consider the case below, where all I did was rename the variable inside of `fun` to be `z` instead of `h` ... yet the same result happens.

```
In [14]: def fun(z):
   ....:     z[:] = z + 1
   ....:     return z
   ....: 

In [15]: h = np.zeros((2,2)) + 1

In [16]: for i in range(0, 3):
   ....:     hI = fun(h)
   ....:     

In [17]: print h
[[ 4.  4.]
 [ 4.  4.]]

In [18]: print hI
[[ 4.  4.]
 [ 4.  4.]]
```

In the first example, the internal variable is not mutated. Assigning

```
h = h + 1
```

causes the *local* `h` (the `h` inside the function scope) to be a *new* name, a name for the object created from the operation `h + 1` for whatever thing was previously named by `h` in that function scope (e.g. the argument that was passed in).

Since the broadcasting operation `h + 1` for a NumPy array `h` results in a *new* array, the statement `h = h + 1` is not mutating `h` ... merely causing the name `h` to refer to something new (`h + 1`).

Whereas in the second example,

```
h[:] = h + 1
```

is to say that the *contents* of whatever object is named by `h` are updated.

You could call it `z[:]` as I did, it doesn't matter. The "thing[:]" on the left hand side is notation for slice assignment, which is implemented for NumPy arrays as a mutation of the sliced object's data.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
def fun(h):
    h=h+1
    return h
```

makes a copy of the input argument `h`. So the input `h` is never changed, even though the variable names happen to be the same (you could use `f = h + 1; return f` or even `return h + 1`; all amounts to the same). You just lose your reference to the input `h`, as you assign it to a new `h`.
Since the input `h` happens to be your original `h` (all 1's), that original never changes, which is what you see in your output.

You add 1 to the original each time (out of three calls to `fun`), but with since the original never changes, it's always an array of 2's.

This

```
def fun(h):
    h[:]=h+1
    return h
```

does alter the input `h`. You change it "in place" by virtue of the `[:]`. So in this case, the returned `h` is the same as input `h`, which is why you see twice the same 2x2 array in your output.
Since you're running this function three times, it gets 1 added to it three times, resulting in all the 4's.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is in the interpretation of the  `=` statement. All is [there](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements) :

Case  `h=h+1` :

> If the target is an identifier (name): the name is bound to the object in the current local namespace.

Case  `h[:]=h+1` :

> If the target is a subscription: The primary expression in the reference is evaluated,and the sequence is asked to assign the assigned object to its item with that index.